# Inherited Classes; How to implement

Tags: python, class, object

Am I inheriting and inserting data into the classes wrong?

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = "Honda"
        self.model = "Minivan"
        self.year = "2010"

class Entry(Car):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, driver, number):
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.driver = "Mike Drosser"
        self.number = 9
    def printEntry(self):
        print("The make is: "+self.make)
        print("The model is: "+self.model)
        print("The year is: "+self.year)

        print("The driver is: "+self.driver)
        self.number = str(self.number)
        print("The number is: "+self.number)

x = Entry()
x.printEntry()
```

Do I have to submit the `Car` class data separately?

Comment: The way you've defined it, make, model, year, driver, number are all **required arguments**.

Comment: You should mention what's not working as expected (error messages, etc.) but at first glance, you're creating an `Entry` object without passing any of the required arguments to the constructor.

Comment: I think you meant to have those values as default parameters.

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146. If you want to ask "what am I doing wrong", then you should pro-actively explain why you think there is something wrong - ideally, by showing the evidence. What happens when you run the code? What is supposed to happen, and how is that different?

Comment: Anyway, I don't think this is really a question about classes. If, instead of two separate `__init__` methods in two separate classes, you had written ordinary functions (with no classes) named `make_car` and `make_entry` with the same functionality, I think you would see the problem immediately. Also, if you are trying to figure out how to make classes work with toy examples, and run into a problem like this, consider *reading and following a tutorial* rather than trying to ask Stack Overflow. Or at least consider using an *actual discussion forum* such as Reddit or Quora.

Comment: Thank you very much good sirs! I am reading through the data provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are 2 problem with your code:

1. the arguments in the constructor are all required, therefore when doing `Entry()` will fail because no arguments were provided.
2. you don't do anything with the provided values to the constructor and instead store specific values in your instance attribute.

Beside that, everything else look fine.

A simple fix is

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make #we store the provided value
        self.model = model
        self.year = year

class Entry(Car):

    def __init__(self, make, model, year, driver, number):
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.driver = driver
        self.number = number
        
    def printEntry(self):
        print("The make is: "+self.make)
        print("The model is: "+self.model)
        print("The year is: "+self.year)

        print("The driver is: "+self.driver)
        self.number = str(self.number)
        print("The number is: "+self.number)

x = Entry("Honda", "Minivan", "2010", "Mike Drosser", 9) #this is how a proper call of this class would look like
x.printEntry()
```

There are other thing that can also be changed, like your prints, the print function can take any number of arguments, so this `print("The number is: "+self.number)` can be change to `print("The number is:", self.number)` this way you don't need to explicitly transform it to a string first in case of numbers or any non-string for that matter.

But in order to be more pythonic, change the printEntry method to the `__str__` special method, that way you can call print in it

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        
    def __str__(self):
        #this method should return a string representation of this class, 
        #for this we use f-string to format the different attributes
        return f"The make is: {self.make}\nThe model is: {self.model}\nThe year is: {self.year}"

class Entry(Car):

    def __init__(self, make, model, year, driver, number):
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.driver = driver
        self.number = number
        
    def __str__(self):
        #here we make use of inheritances to split job 
        #by letting the Car class handle the part it 
        #know about and this subclass will add to it 
        #with the part exclusive to it
        return super().__str__() + f"\nThe driver is: {self.driver}\nThe number is: {self.number}"
        
        

x = Entry("Honda", "Minivan", "2010", "Mike Drosser", 9)
print(x)
```

Comment: I get this error `  File "part4.py", line 27, in <module>
    x = Entry("Honda", "Minivan", "2010", "Mike Drosser", 9) #this is how a proper call of this class would look like
  File "part4.py", line 14, in __init__
    super().__init__(make, model, year)
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`

Comment: @ArcOfficial this sample code as is give no error, neither super requires any argument, there is something else going on in that file of yours that is causing that error

Comment: Actually the second bit of code returns this: `File "part4.py", line 14
    return f"The make is: {self.make}\nThe model is: {self.model}\nThe year is: {self.year}"
                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`

Comment: syntax error? what version of python are you using?

Comment: Python 3 is the version that I am using

Comment: Thank you very much for bringing attention. My version of python was at 2, and now I am running it on 3, and it works.

Comment: Let me uptick your answer, if you could do the same that would be great.

Comment: cool, as you notice there are many small differences between python version, f-string were introduce in 3.6 and super was change from requiring arguments in 2 to not required them in 3